# How to show an error when Firebase Realtime Database denies access?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My app retrieves data from my Firebase Database. The data retrieved is viewed in a TextView. Before retrieving the TextView just shows the hint(username here).

While writing the rules in Firebase Database, I turned ".read" and ".write" both to FALSE. That means no one can access the data.

But then my TextView remains showing the hint. How do I get a response in the app that Access is denied so that I can create a pop-up stating that ACCESS is DENIED.

Any way to get such confirmation?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

so when my rules are as above.
The output is:

[image]

but when I change the rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

The output is:

[image]

So the user thinks that his cash is still loading, but i want to show him an error that ACCESS DENIED. Any way to do so?

My code:

```
String cashOwnValue = "start";
try {
    cashOwnValue = dataSnapshot.child("startCash").getValue().toString();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
cashValue.setText(cashOwnValue);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your balance has changed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**EDIT:**
When the access is denied, then to let user know that his request has been denied you have to code this:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Access Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and to avoid app crash if user data is not found, you have use try-catch block, as answered below. (which also took a long discussion with @PrajwalW to be solved).

Comment: Paste your fb rules logic here. Also, just set your write to FALSE and read to True...

Comment: Also, u can do a quicklogic that if the fb rtdb object value is null then show a pop up.

Comment: Please edit the question to show all of the relevant rules, as well as the code that performs the query that isn't working the way you expect.  We should be able to duplicate the issue based on what you provide.

Comment: @PrajwalW I added the rules and screenshots.

Comment: Refer my comments u will get the ans..

Comment: @PrajwalW when access is denied, it won't even return null value i guess??

Comment: hv u tried?....Also u can use a try catch block in that case then...

Comment: @PrajwalW i tried. i do get an error "W/SyncTree: Listen at /Agent/username failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied".. im thinking of how can I use this error to return access denied pop up.

Comment: Its a runtime error right? I said u to put a try-catch block !!!

Comment: @PrajwalW try catch block is working just one issue. I had initialised the string by value "start". It won't update the value. It will print Start instead of cashValue. PLease check above updated code

Comment: You wnat cashvalue right?

Comment: @PrajwalW yes cashOwnValue(string). cashValue is ID of TextView.. In c++. To update a string we just need to do `string a="abc"; a="xyz"` to update string .. thats the currnt problem now.. unable to update string

Comment: Please check my ans....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go a complete single solution:

1. Make read = True and write = False. This will only allow read access and will return Permission denied on write access.
2. To handle that error: use a try - catch block to execute.
3. In try block write your code and in catch block handle your exception.
4. As per your condition, you want to show error or default text when user try to edit the field. For that write that code in your catch block.
5. Now your new error msg of text doesnt update:

**Make this changes:**

String cashOwnValue = null;   //Globally set to null initial value.

```
        try {
            cashOwnValue = "start";
            cashOwnValue = dataSnapshot.child("startCash").getValue().toString();
            cashValue.setText(cashOwnValue);  //add the setText() inside the try block like this...
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your balance has changed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: no . .adding setText(); in try block says `Variable 'cashOwnValue' initializer '"start"' is redundant` .. and wont work.

Comment: and if i dont initialize the string it says `error: variable cashOwnValue might not have been initialized`

Comment: you mean public string at top of the code?? didnt worked

Comment: Man.....what u want to do? what is the use of that try block explain in one line! Also paste the code not image...

Comment: The string is initialized to "Start". When the data is retrieved from firebase database. String should hold value of data retrieved instead of "start". I want to change value of string fro "start" to dataRetrieved

Comment: String cashOwnValue = "Start" // at the top inside your class.

try {
cashOwnValue = dataSnapshot.child("startCash").getValue().toString();
            cashValue.setText(cashOwnValue);  
}

Comment: Happy that you finally got it working!!! If useful pls upvote too! :)

Comment: It worked. Please do check my EDIT in original question also. Please correct your answer as well, i mean move the string initialization to top and set initial value to `null` instead of "start". Thanks for the help. Here is the screenshot of working code: [Click here for screenshot](https://imgur.com/LOvOOxD)

Comment: My rep. is low to upvote. Do you have telegram handle btw??

Comment: Have made the necessary changes...Aah that fine....Happy that I was of some help to you! Happy Coding! :) I dont use telegram btw..

Comment: As far as it is not a confidential data or any company security data I think you shouldnt worry about it. Also, if you have correctly defined your Firebase database rules, no one can access it. Also, if u havent shared your project id of firebase or password with anyone .

Comment: But if anyone does that, he can mess with players data. Players account will have ".write" set to true in rules. So is there any way that users can write to firebase databse from my signed apk from playstore only and not from any other modded apk?